# Is there a minimum height between bottom of window and the slope?

Tags: windows

We are getting new windows installed by a contractor.  They mismeasured the window size so they had to cut out part of the bottom of the frame (where it slopes down to drain water) to make it fit.  They cut about 1" deep and 4" wide.  Now the window fits, but the drain ports are awful close to the slope (see pic) and they still need to put the new wrap on.  It just doesn't look right and cutting that chann out doesn't seem right either....but I know nothing about it.  I'm afraid water will get in the channel somehow and sit there and rot the wood.

Am I making mountains out of mole hills here, or will this be fine if caulk properly?  Also, the drains seem too close to the slope.  Is this OK, or does the building code say something about this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How about a profile view.

Comment: @JACK What do you mean by profile view?  I can stand farther back and slightly more to the side.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Just more to the side  so we can get an idea of the sloping.

Comment: @JACK I uploaded another picture.

Comment: You are making a mountain out of nothing. There is a slope. If you are concerned (and I would) place a bead of calking to prevent wind from driving the water under the frame if there is a chance for water to migrate back to the cut out. See Lee Sam’s answer, rot resistant wood should be used here in the first place.

Comment: Is that base board flashed with some material like vinyl or aluminum, or is it just painted wood?

Comment: @TylerH The baseboard has aluminum on it right now and will get new aluminum put on before they are done.

Comment: @tnknepp That's good; I would think new aluminum and a bead of caulk (re-applied every 10-15 years, of course) would be plenty for water concerns, looking at the existing tilt/slope of the sill.

Answer (score -3):

All wood within 8” of the ground shall be protected with “approved species and grade of lumber and pressure treated in accordance with AWPA, or use decay resistant heartwood of redwood, black locus or cedar.” (See ICC R319.1)

Lumber will rot close to the ground due to water splashing up on a wall. Don’t allow it.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question? It's asking about window sills and water runoff, not ground contact lumber regulations.

Comment: @TylerH If you read the op’s question, you’ll see they cut the bottom part of the window out and now it’s down close to the slope.

Comment: I read it as close to the slope*d windowsill*, not close to the ground.

Comment: @brhans That's right.  The sloped windowsill, not the ground.

Comment: Looks like a lot of people do not have a clue that a drain like this is normal and proper wood type reduces the issues of rot. 1 down vote reversed. Water dripping from the drain is the same as splashing from the ground.

Comment: @LeeSam It looks like you are conflating "slope" with "ground". It seems clear (especially now that there is a second photo showing the window sill is ~4 feet off the ground, and a comment here by OP confirming this) that by "slope" OP is referring to the *sloped window sill*.